# Xamarin: How do you set a breakpoint in a simple C++ project?

Tags: c++, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am new to Xamarin Studio. I am trying to set a breakpoint in a C++ project's  automatically created main.cpp file, which contains a hello world line only. I am on Xamarin Studio Community 5.10.3 (build 51) on Mac. The solution is created from a template in Other->Miscellaneous->C/C++->Console Project->CPP. While debugging I am setting a breakpoint but execution won't stop at the breakpoint. How to make the debugger to stop there?

Answer (score 1):

There should be two options to run the program, "Start Without Debugging" and "Start With Debugging" under the "Run" toolbar at the top. You must use the second option to have the program stop at the breakpoint. Are you running the program with the little "run" arrow icon? If so, that starts the program without the debugger. You must select the "Start With Debugging" option under the "Run" toolbar.

Comment: In the "Run" menu, there are two options: "Start Without Debugging" and "Start Debugging", however the latter is grayed out. Also, "Step Into" and "Step Over", etc. are also grayed out. - Not sure what you mean by "Run" toolbar. - I indeed try to use the "run" arrow at the top to run the program.

Comment: The "Run" menu and "Run" toolbar are the same thing. 

Anyway, the reason you aren't able to do this is because you don't have a debugger installed for C++ under Xamarin Studio. Xamarin Studio comes built in with a debugger for C# and VB.Net, because these are the languages it is mostly intended for. However, after some Googling, I don't know if there is a gdb (GNU Debugger, standard for C++ and C applications) plugin for OSX. Perhaps see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/